# ffmpeg join two mp4 files with ffmpeg on command line

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I can successfully join multiple files using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mp4
```

The only problem with this command is that you need to read the filepaths from the text file called **input.txt** with the following content:

```
file 'C:\Users\fabio\Downloads\Super\Sharks\01.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\fabio\Downloads\Super\Sharks\02.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\fabio\Downloads\Super\Sharks\03.mp4'
```

Is there a way to achieve the same goal without having to read the filepaths from a file? I have tried the following with no luck:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i file "C:\a\b\01.mp4" file "C:\a\b\02.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i "C:\a\b\01.mp4" "C:\a\b\02.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4
```

Do I have to use a different command?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### 2019 Update:

As mentioned in the comments, Stack Overflow has a great description of the available options for concatenation, as well as a discussion of which method to use depending on the types of files you're using:

[How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)

### Original 2016 Answer:

You should be able to use the [concat protocol](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol) method to combine the files:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.mp4|input2.mp4|input3.mp4" -c copy output.mp4
```

In addition, the FFmpeg manual discusses a method specifically for MP4 files, in order to losslessly concatenate them, but requires that you create temporary files (or named pipes):

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Comment: Sweet!... Thank you!  The first method didn't work for me but the second did the trick. I don't have a problem creating intermediate files as long as I don't have to read inputs ( filepaths) from a file. This is crucial for the project I am working on... thanks again

Comment: Oh and the FFmpeg manual you are referring to is it the website FFmpeg.org or is it in a PDF or book version?

Comment: I was just referring to FFmpeg.org, specifically the concat protocol section (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol). Their documentation can be a little hard to read through, but it does cover a ton of use cases.

Comment: First command worked for me like a butter..it took 2 to 3 seconds to concat my 6 mp4 files into output file (239 MB approx).

Comment: The first command didn't work for me. It just copied the first file.

Comment: The same here: the first command just copied the first file; the second command does the trick... but the output file has no audio!

Comment: At what version was this feature introduced? Debian 9 (with version 3.3.7) simply says "concat:.....mp4: No such file or directory" and quits.

Comment: I guess the first command only works depending on the source MP4. The named pipes method worked without issues, audio came ok. SO's q&a is more complete regarding the various concat techniques: [How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333232/1287812)

Comment: This doesn't work, it just copied the first file to `output.mp4`.

Comment: @crmpicco, the same problem, regardless the file have the same codec, same framerate and created by the same program. Found an alternative solution.

Comment: File-level concatenation does not work for MP4, so the concat protocol is not recommended for this format and will generally not work.

Comment: @brasofilo Thank you for the link. This is long overdue, but I updated the answer to point people in that direction.

Comment: Didn't work on .mp4s, but this did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/1432614

Comment: What does the `-c copy` option does? It seems to work without.

Comment: The last option can also be done with pipes instead of temporary files, e.g. `(
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts - &&
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts - 
) | ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -i - -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc combined.mp4`. The trailing `-`es and `-i -` mean to use standard output and input, respectively.

Answer (score 11):

You may replace file with list by outputting list to `stdout` and reading the list from `stdin` by ffmpeg:

```bsh
(echo file 'a.mp4' & echo file 'b.mp4') | ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -f concat -safe 0 -i pipe: -vcodec copy -acodec copy "result.mp4"
```

Comment: Using ffmpeg version 2.4.3-tessus on Mac OS 10.12.6, this just throws an error: "Unrecognized option 'protocol_whitelist'". Without the protocol_whitelist option, it seems to just make a copy of the second MP4 file.

Comment: @ErmanKadirKahraman, singleline form is fine for both windows and linux, but trailing ```\``` makes it correct only for linux as windows uses `^` as escaping for linebreak.

Comment: @ErmanKadirKahraman, buy the way, I'm not sure if it works in linux at all as its `echo file 'a.mp4'` prints `file a.mp4` when on windows it keeps apostrophe `file 'a.mp4'`.

Comment: This is best answer I found after search for hours , it even works on shell script .

Comment: I also liked this best. I posted a 'script' based on this idea.

Comment: @James, have you tried to escape apostrophes?

Answer (score 2):

No, there appears to be no way to use the ffmpeg concat demuxer on a single command line without some hack. You need to create the input text file with the list of files. I thought this strange myself, maybe someone will add this to FFMpeg at a later date.

The accepted answer to this question uses the concat protocol, not the concat demuxer which is what the OP asked.

Comment: Actually there is. stdin.

Comment: concat protocol shouldn't be used with MP4 or any other format the requires a global header.

Answer (score 2):

Without external text file, one line command to merge all MP4 files in a folder:

in **CMD** (the Command Prompt):

```
(FOR /R %A IN (*.mp4) DO @ECHO file '%A') | ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -f concat -safe 0 -i pipe: -vcodec copy -acodec copy "Videos_Merged.mp4"
```

in a **BAT**ch file:

```
(FOR /R %%A IN (*.mp4) DO @ECHO file '%%A') | ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -f concat -safe 0 -i pipe: -vcodec copy -acodec copy "Videos_Merged.mp4"
```

P.S.: `CHCP 65001` command need if the directory contains unicode characaters.

(This code based **Qwertiy**'s one-line command. I'm again grateful to **Qwertiy** for the informations in his reply. So I fixed the code.

Comment: Not sure that you need `dir` command - `for` hase some forms that iterate filenames. Also a questionable moment is order of files - I'm not sure whether it sorts the list somehow or not.

Comment: @Qwertiy , thanks for the code and your reply. Actually, your're right. `FOR %G IN (*.mp4) Do @echo %G` - It lists MP4s properly.  I recorded a few some videos today. Filenames: 

VID_20210706_170844.mp4
...
VID_20210706_174446.mp4

This code doesn't work:

`(FOR %A IN (*.mp4) DO @ECHO file '%A') | ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -f concat -safe 0 -i pipe: -vcodec copy -acodec copy "Videos_Merged.mp4"` 

I updated the last properly working code in my post.

Comment: Yep, nice. Already upvoted the answer last time.

Answer (score 2):

GoPro 'chapters' are footage around 4 GB - The camera starts a new file every ~ 10 minutes. If you have media files with exactly the same codec and codec parameters you can concatenate them quite easily. Fastest way, that I found, is use ffmpeg with concating function:

```bsh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in *.MP4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could still do it in a script without changing the command. Something like:

```
echo "file fname1" >$$.tmp    #single redirect creates or truncates file
echo "file fname2" >>$$.tmp   # double redirect appends
echo "file fname3" >>$$.tmp   # do as many as you want.

ffmpeg -f concat -i $$.tmp -codec copy output.mp4

rm $$.tmp  # just to clean up the temp file. 
           # For debugging, I usually leave this out.
```

The $$ expands to the pid of the shell running the command, so the file name will be different every time you run it. so you could use $$.txt if you prefer. Or something else...

Also, you can use here files to add a bunch of data to the file:

```
cat <<EOF >$$.tmp
file fname1
file fname2
file fname3
EOF
```

bash Variable substitution works, so you can programatically determine the content of the file, it doesn't have to be fixed. I embed this sort of stuff in for loops all the time. Finally, the redirect works the same as above, so >$$.tmp truncates then writes, >>$$.tmp appends.

Comment: The question asks, "is there a way to achieve the same goal without having to read the filepaths from a file?"  All you have done is provide a way to write the filepaths to a file (prior to reading the filepaths from the file).  This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I also liked Qwertiy's answer best. Here is a script (works for an arbitrary number of files, also for `.mov`; tested on macOS):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` input_1.mp4 input_2.mp4 ... output.mp4"
    exit 0
fi

ARGS=("$@") # determine all arguments
output=${ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}-1]} # get the last argument (output file)
unset ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}-1] # drop it from the array
(for f in "${ARGS[@]}"; do echo "file '$f'"; done) | ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,pipe -f concat -safe 0 -i pipe: -vcodec copy -acodec copy $output
```