# How to concat 2 mp4 videos by ffmpeg without having a messing result?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to concat 2 mp4 videos with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1). But the resulted video is not perfect.

My `files.txt`, to point the videos to be concatenated:

```
file 'cutted1.mp4'
file 'cutted2.mp4'
```

The ffmpeg command used:

`$ ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy result_ffmpeg.mp4`

After the concat, the resulted video has many messes:

- Lost the first seconds from the second video;
- Freeze the last seconds from the second video;
- Output a lot of warnings, like this: `Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 479509, current: 361106; changing to 479510. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.`

Last, My full terminal output:

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy result_ffmpeg.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55a7392081c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'files.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.023220, bitrate: 2167 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2041 kb/s, 23.81 fps, 23.81 tbr, 16k tbn, 47.62 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'result_ffmpeg.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2041 kb/s, 23.81 fps, 23.81 tbr, 16k tbn, 16k tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55a7392081c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 0x55a73920d420] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 479508, current: 360606; changing to 479509. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55a73920d420] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 479509, current: 361106; changing to 479510. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

...(more of the same warnings removed for better readability)

[mp4 @ 0x55a73920d420] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 479744, current: 478606; changing to 479745. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55a73920d420] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 479745, current: 479106; changing to 479746. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55a73920d420] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 479746, current: 479606; changing to 479747. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame= 1437 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   15403kB time=00:01:00.24 bitrate=2094.3kbits/s speed= 670x    
video:14426kB audio:930kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.306242%
```

So, how to concat the videos correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Briefing

Using ffmpeg, I can concatenate the 2 videos by generating a `*.ts` file for each video file.
It is the file extension to the *Video Transport Stream File* type.
This format worked like a intermediate file format: this files standardize the two different videos and soften them to be concatenated after.

## Coding

The commands to concatenate are:

- Step 0: Seeing our folder, we have.

```bash
$ ls ./
cutted1.mp4  cutted2.mp4
```

- Step 1: generate `*.ts` files from each of the 2 videos files.

```bash
$ ffmpeg -i cutted1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
$ ffmpeg -i cutted2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
```

- Step 2: Seeing our folder, we have the two `*.ts` files:

```bash
$ ls ./
cutted1.mp4  cutted2.mp4  intermediate1.ts  intermediate2.ts
```

- Step 3: concatenate the 2 *.ts files:

```bash
$ ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

- Step 4: Seeing our folder finnally, we have:

```bash
$ ls ./
cutted1.mp4  cutted2.mp4  intermediate1.ts  intermediate2.ts  output.mp4
```

## References:

These links helped me to resolve my problem:

- [Concat protocol, using intermediate files](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol)
- [Resolving the problem *ffmpeg throwing “Non-monotonous DTS in output stream”*](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/390400-ffmpeg-throwing-NNon-monotonous-DTS-in-output-stream#post2537545)
- [Video Transport Stream File type ref 1](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ts)
- [Video Transport Stream File type ref 2](https://www.lifewire.com/ts-file-4151262)
- [Good answer from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216101/1467021)
- [Convert first to intermediate format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27299384/1467021)
- [Join 2 vids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32179471/1467021)
- [Join 2 mp4](https://superuser.com/a/1059261/1062554)
- [Merge 2 mp4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378444)

## Did not worked:

For my case, the list bellow did not solved my problem.
But maybe, it can resolve your problem.

(Attn: Stackoverflow avoid me to post an answer with more the 8 links. So I typed the links bellow in a non- formated way. Please if any moderator consider them useful, edit the urls bellow to be link-clickable. Thanks.)

So, I'm listing them for reference:

- [Concat demuxer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122772/1467021)
- [Concat demuxer wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer)
- [Concat ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)
- [Problaby best Stackoverflow answer about ffmpeg concat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/1467021)
- [Concat protocol instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49373401/1467021)
- [Concatenating using the concat protocol (file level)](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Concatenating-using-the-concat-protocol-_0028file-level_0029)
- [ffmpeg “Non-monotonous DTS in output stream” concatenating .ts files](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/391884-ffmpeg-NNon-monotonous-DTS-in-output-stream-concatenating-ts-files)
- [Non-Monotonous DTS on concat (ffmpeg)](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/non-monotonous-dts-on-concat-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

almost 5 years later, let me say: wow, this was so helpful.  thanks for taking the time to post the answer to your own question.  ffmpeg isn't designed for imperfect video sources (dashcams, security cameras) with dropout, etc, so the usual concat commands either choke or generate non-viable outputs (videos which freeze).

The commands look so simple, but clearly it took a lot of research and effort on your part to come to this answer!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240363)